# How do i add an API Key to this Youtube Data API request?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

From this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

The below code snippet shows how to run a search query against the YT data api.

```
def search_list_by_keyword(client, **kwargs):

    kwargs = remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs)

    response = client.search().list(
         **kwargs
    ).execute()

    return print_response(response)

search_list_by_keyword(client,
    part='snippet',
    maxResults=25,
    q='surfing',
    type='')
```

How do i add an API key to this request so that it is authorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the API key using **"key"** parameter.

**Example**:

```
search_list_by_keyword(client,
    part='snippet',
    maxResults=25,
    q='surfing',
    key="YOUR_API_KEY",                        
    type='')
```

Examples using CURL:

```
# curl URL:
curl -i -G -d "part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing&key={YOUR_API_KEY}"
              https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search

# HTTP URL:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet
                                                &maxResults=25
                                                &q=surfing
                                                &key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Your API key to the code

```
search_list_by_keyword(client,
    part='snippet',
    maxResults=25,
    q='surfing',
   key='your_api_key',
    type='')
```

After that, you will get authorize to the YouTube API and to see whether your API request was successful or not you can check your developer API for this on google developer [Google API Services](https://console.developers.google.com/) under your API details you can check the count of request number if it is more than zero then you have successfully authorized to API.

API request image:
[image]